# Netty TCP server characters become garbage

Tags: java, tcp, netty

I have assigned to do TCP server in my organization to receive text message and split them. But unfortunately some of my
message characters become garbage (I have used JMeter as my TCP client). I have 2 questions related to this problem. Any help is highly appreciated.

> 1. Why we can not split my message using "»" (u00BB) character? It never worked and how we could use "»" as delimiter in `DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder`?
> 2. Why we receive garbage characters although I used `UTF-8` in encoding/decoding? (Only manage to receive messages when I comment `"pipeline.addLast("frameDecoder", new io.netty.handler.codec.DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder( 500000, byteDeli)"` )

Sample request:

```
pov1‹1‹202030‹81056581‹0‹6‹565810000011‹0‹130418135639‹3‹4‹0‹cha7373737›chaE15E2512380›1›1«ban7373737›banE15E2512380›2›2«ind7373737›indE15E2512380›3›3»
```

Eclipse cosole: Recieved Request ::::::

```
pov1�1�202030�81056581�0�6�565810000011�0�130418135639�3�4�0�cha7373737�chaE15E2512380�1�1�ban7373737�banE15E2512380�2�2�ind7373737�indE15E2512380�3�3�
```

Server class:-

```
public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("2:run");
                bootstrap
                        .group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                        .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                        .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                            @Override
                            public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch)
                                    throws Exception {
                                ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
                                DTMTCPServiceHandler serviceHandler = context
                                        .getBean(DTMTCPServiceHandler.class);
                                pipeline.addFirst(new LoggingHandler(
                                        LogLevel.INFO));
                                
                                byte[] delimiter = "\u00BB".getBytes(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);//»
                                ByteBuf byteDeli = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(delimiter);                                
                                
                                pipeline.addLast(
                                        "frameDecoder",
                                        new io.netty.handler.codec.DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(
                                                500000, byteDeli)); // Decoders
                                pipeline.addLast("stringDecoder",
                                        new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
                                pipeline.addLast("stringEncoder",
                                        new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
                                pipeline.addLast("messageHandler",
                                        serviceHandler);

                            }
                        }).option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                        .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
                serverChannel = bootstrap.bind(7070).sync().channel()
                        .closeFuture().sync().channel();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //error
                logger.error("POSGatewayServiceThread : InterruptedException",
                        e);
                System.out.println(e);
            } finally {
                //finally
                System.out.println("finally");
                serverChannel.close();
                workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
                bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            }

        }
```

Handler class

```
public class DTMTCPServiceHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        String posMessage = msg.toString();
        
        System.out.println("Recieved Request :::::: " + posMessage);
        String response = "-";
        ByteBuf copy = null;
        try {
            //Called to separate splitter class
            response = dtmtcpServiceManager.manageDTMTCPMessage(posMessage);
            copy = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(response.getBytes());

        } finally {
            logger.info("Recieved Response :::::: " + response);
            ctx.write(copy);
            ctx.flush();
        }

    }       
    
    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        //Open
        super.channelActive(ctx);
    }       
    
    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        //End
        super.channelReadComplete(ctx);
    }
    
            @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        //exception
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the Eclipse console show the characters properly when you write `System.out.println("« ›");`?

Comment: Yes, I just checked it now and it shows characters correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem and it is not related to netty. Error is with the JMeter encoding. managed to solve this after modifying the "jmeter.properties" property file @\apache-jmeter-x.xx\bin.

```
tcp.charset=UTF-8
```

Sorry to trouble you guys, since false is with me.